# Wordpress - using 'get_post' to select only those posts that are in two specified cats at once

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use 'get_posts' to pick up posts that are in two categories. Currently I am using this:
`$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&category=4&category=7');`

This picks up posts that are either in category 4 or 7. The posts I want to pick up must be in both categories at once. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&category=4,7');
```